# Nuget Packages not installing anything in .net core app

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, knockout.js, nuget

I am trying to install knockoutjs and typescript in a .net core app via Nuget.

It shows in Packages but doesn't install anything in a scripts folder as has previously in asp.net.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR ASP.NET Core no longer works in that way (packages copying javascript/css content into your project). You need to adapt your workflow.

.NET Core projects only work in SDK-style projects, and SDK style projects only use NuGet's `PackageReference`, not `packages.config`. The [docs on migrating from `packages.config` to `PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) list one [package compatibility issue as not supporting the `content` folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#content-assets-are-not-available-when-the-package-is-installed-after-the-migration), which is how in `packages.config` those assets are copied into your project on package install.

I can't find a doc listing recommendations for ASP.NET Core apps, but my understanding is you can either use [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/?view=aspnetcore-3.1), or use NPM, which is in line with basically the rest of the web development industry outside of .NET has been doing. If you use the new project templates to create a new ASP.NET Core Angular or ASP.NET Core React app, you'll see they create a `ClientApp` folder that uses npm and all the official react/angular CLI tools. The MVC template has copies of jQuery and bootstrap, without an obvious way how to update them.

Answer (score 0):

might be some unsync, remove the packages folder from the solution and restore the packages again. It will fix the issue. Also check the output window, that will show the list of errors.

Comment: There is no ability to remove the Packages folder from the Visual Studio UI and there is no packages folder in Windows Explorer either.

Answer (score 0):

> It shows in Packages but doesn't install anything in a scripts folder
>   as has previously in asp.net.

**First**, I agree with **zivkan**. It is a feature of [PackageReference Nuget Management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

VS has two format to manage nuget packages: **Packages.config** and **PackageReference**.

Since new sdk format projects(`Net Core` and `Net Standard`) only use **PackageReference** to manage nuget packages,it will be very different from the effect reflected by the [packages.config package management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config).

When you use **Content** files from the nuget packages with **PackageReference**, it will lose files from the Scripts folder.

Just as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#package-compatibility-issues) said, it has such compatibility issues.

[image]

**Actually**, you can enter `C:\Users\xxxx\.nuget\packages\knockoutjs\3.5.1` and find there is a folder called **Content**, Nuget will copy the content of that folder into your project when you install this nuget package.

But **Content** folder can be recognized by `Packages.config` format, and as far as I know, **ContentFiles** folder is used in **PackageReference** to add the content into your project. So in your situation, the nuget package should include **ContentFiles** folder at the same time. See [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files).

But the `knockoutjs` nuget package does not have contentfiles folder. That is why net framework projects with `packages.config` has  the content files while new sdk projects does not have it.

**And** this behavior change can only be effective when you create the nuget package, so you ca n’t make any kind of change, you can only contact the author of the package to make this modification, and let him add this function as soon as possible to apply to the new SDK format project.

**Suggestion**

So So for now, you can try these:

**1)** you can either manually Add the content file from `C:\Users\xxxx\.nuget\packages\knockoutjs\xxxx\Content` to the project by **Adding Existing Items**.

**2)** roll back to use Net Framework projects with `packages.config`.

**3)** contact with the author on [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/knockoutjs/).