# jQuery not found when migrating to PackageReferences

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package, packagereference

I've migrated to PackageReference for my ASP.NET MVC web project.
The first issue that occurred is that it says that my project is not eligible so I had to remove this line `<ProjectTypeGuids>` from the `.csproj` file in order to be able to migrate.

After that, I've been able to do a successful migration, so I've put `<ProjectTypeGuids>` back.

The issue that occurred now is that I can't find jQuery js files at any location of the project.

It's displayed in References and in "Manage Nuget Packages" that I've the latest version installed , but I can't find it anywhere to reference it.

I really don't want to put manually the JS files because I wont be able to update the libraries automatically from "Manage Nuget Packages". So the only way here is to determine how can I see and reference those JS files.

What am I missing here ?

I've tried the migration on an empty ASP.NET MVC / C# web  project. The script folder is removed on migration and the JS files are not available anywhere.

I've removed and reinstalled the package but not luck. I've restarted Visual Studio, rebuild, cleaned, removed the obj and bin folder data but same outcome.

Comment: Off topic: TBH you *probably* don't want to upgrade jquery via nuget packages as there's usually a lot more to it than a simple upgrade.  eg using [tag:jquery-migrate]

Comment: "When you use Content files from the nuget packages with PackageReference, it will lose files from the Scripts folder."   Have a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012147/razor-core-installing-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-missing-js-files)   and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483582/nuget-packages-not-installing-anything-in-net-core-app) .

Comment: Totally true, the files in Scripts folder are removed but since jQuery is installed a PackageReference it must be added somewhere else in the project and I need just to change the /App_Start/BundleConfig.cs . The issue here I can't find jQuery files anywhere in the application folder.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, JS files based libraries ( like jQuery, moment.js,.. )  must be added manually to the project and not managed by Nuget Package Manager  ?